# StanfordCoreNLPClient don't work as expected on sentiment analysis

Tags: stanford-nlp

Stanford CoreNLP version 3.9.1

I have a problem getting `StanfordCoreNLPClient` work the same way as `StanfordCoreNLP` when doing sentiment analysis.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This server doesn't work!";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment");

    //If I uncomment this line, and comment out the next one, it works                            
    //StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    StanfordCoreNLPClient pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLPClient(props, "http://localhost", 9000, 2);

    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(annotation);           
    CoreSentence sentence = document.sentences().get(0);

    //outputs null when using StanfordCoreNLPClient
    System.out.println(RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictions(sentence.sentimentTree())); 

    //throws null pointer when using StanfordCoreNLPClien (reason of course is that it uses the same method I called above, I assume)   
    System.out.println(RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictionsAsStringList(sentence.sentimentTree()));  

}
```

}

Output using `StanfordCoreNLPClient pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLPClient(props, "http://localhost", 9000, 2)`:

```
 null
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictionsAsStringList(RNNCoreAnnotations.java:68)
at tomkri.mastersentimentanalysis.preprocessing.Test.main(Test.java:35)
```

Output using `StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)`:

```
     Type = dense , numRows = 5 , numCols = 1
     0.127  
     0.599  
     0.221  
     0.038  
     0.015  

     [0.12680336652661395, 0.5988695516384742, 0.22125584263055106, 0.03843574738131668, 0.014635491823044227]
```

Other annotations than sentiment works in both cases (at least those I have tried).

The server starts fine, and I am able to use from my web browser. When using it there I also get output of sentiment scores (on each subtree in the parse) in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, in case anyone else need it.

I tried to get the required annotation by making http request to the server with JSON response:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9000")
       .queryString("properties", "{\"annotators\":\"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment\",\"outputFormat\":\"json\"}")
       .body(text)
       .asJson();

String sentTreeStr = jsonResponse.getBody().getObject().
                getJSONArray("sentences").getJSONObject(0).getString("sentimentTree");

System.out.println(sentTreeStr); //prints out sentiment values for tree and all sub trees.
```

But not all annotation data is available. For example, you don't get the probability distribution over all the possible
sentiment values, only the probability of the sentiment most likely (the sentiment with highest probability).

If you need that, this is a solution:

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> inStream = Unirest.post("http://localhost:9000")
        .queryString(
                "properties", 
                "{\"annotators\":\"tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment\","
                + "\"outputFormat\":\"serialized\","
                + "\"serializer\": \"edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.GenericAnnotationSerializer\"}"
        )
        .body(text)
        .asBinary();

GenericAnnotationSerializer  serializer = new GenericAnnotationSerializer ();
try{
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inStream.getBody());
        Pair<Annotation, InputStream> deserialized = serializer.read(in);
        Annotation annotation = deserialized.first();           

        //And now we are back to a state as if we were not running CoreNLP as server.
        CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(annotation);         
        CoreSentence sentence = document.sentences().get(0);
        //Prints out same output as shown in question  
        System.out.println(
            RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictions(sentence.sentimentTree()));

} catch (UnirestException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(SentimentTargetExtractor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```